# updating apps without play store

Tags: applications, updates

How can I update apps that I've installed via .apk file on a phone without Google Play Store?

I would not mind downloading the updated .apk files manually, but is there a way to get notified when an update is available for one of my installed apps?

Comment: Not sure if it works w/o GApps on the device, but might be worth a look: [App Watcher - Updates notifier](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anod.appwatcher). For more alternatives, be welcome to check with my [App Markets](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_markets) listings :)

Comment: @Izzy Some of the links from that page is very much useful as an answer. Please make one

Answer (score 2):

There are several possibilities, depending on your sources:

- use one of the [alternative-markets](/questions/tagged/alternative-markets)<sup>**1**</sup> as source (recommendation: F-Droid with its pre-configured main repo plus some of the [additional repositories accessible with their app](http://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/list-of-fdroid-repos)), and get information about available updates via the corresponding market's app
- use an alternative "update checker" such as [App Watcher - Updates notifier](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anod.appwatcher) (you can find some more in my [App Markets](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_markets) listing)
- use an application on your PC to check for updates (see the same listing<sup>**2**</sup> for candidates). For example, *Raccoon* is planning such a feature for its new version (not sure about its release, though – the author was quite busy with its "graduation" and just finished his university degree recently).

---

<sup><sup>**1:**</sup></sup> <sub>Also see the [alternative-markets tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/alternative-markets/info) and follow its links</sub>
<sup><sup>**2:**</sup></sup> <sub>I won't list all the candidates here, as they might be subject to change. The linked lists however will be kept up-to-date.</sub>

---

<sup>**Disclaimer:** For those not aware, and in case I didn't make it obvious enough: those listings reside on my own website.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using the [APKPure](http://apkpure.com) app, it is possible to receive Play Store-like notifications about updates.

I frequently use this app instead of the Play Store. It also allows you to download previous versions.

Comment: I just have a question, although it might be marked as off topic.  I was wondering why a lot of people don't like the Play Store, or why many people want to disable it.  I use an alternative app store too, but I still use the Play Store to download the majority of my apps.

Comment: @Mario I think it is because some people do not want a Google Account.